# Clone an element by jQuery with refreshing the value depends on the original element when increment or decrement occur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all I would like you to know that before I make a post here I read a lot about this subject but still can't apply the idea so this post is after long time of searching...

### This is HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test&#8378;</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <nav style="height: 30px; width: 100%; background-color: dodgerblue"></nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="menu col-sm-6">
                    <div class="mealType burger">
                        <div class="categoryTitle">Burger</div>
                        <div class="categoryContent" id="burger">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="images/meal.png" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>Chicken Burger</td>
                                    <td>18<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                    <td class="add">+</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>0<span>x</span></td>
                                    <td>0<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="images/meal.png" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>Fish Burger</td>
                                    <td>15<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                    <td class="add">+</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>0<span>x</span></td>
                                    <td>0<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="images/meal.png" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>Barbeque</td>
                                    <td>12<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                    <td class="add">+</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>0<span>x</span></td>
                                    <td>0<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mealType seaFood">
                        <div class="categoryTitle">Sea Food</div>
                        <div class="categoryContent" id="seaFood">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="images/meal.png" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>Fish Sliece</td>
                                    <td>18<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                    <td class="add">+</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>0<span>x</span></td>
                                    <td>0<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="images/meal.png" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>Fillet Fish</td>
                                    <td>25<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                    <td class="add">+</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td class="add">0<span>x</span></td>
                                    <td>0<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="images/meal.png" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>Hamour Fish</td>
                                    <td>40<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                    <td class="add">+</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>0<span>x</span></td>
                                    <td>0<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mealType steak">
                        <div class="categoryTitle">Steak</div>
                        <div class="categoryContent" id="seaFood">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="images/meal.png" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>Chicken Steak</td>
                                    <td>18<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                    <td class="add">+</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>0<span>x</span></td>
                                    <td>0<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="images/meal.png" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>Beef Steak</td>
                                    <td>25<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                    <td class="add">+</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>0<span>x</span></td>
                                    <td>0<span>&#8378;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myCart col-sm-6">
                    <div class="myCartContaier">
                        <div class="myCartTitle">My Cart</div>
                        <div class="myCartDetails">
                            <table></table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### Javascript jQuery Code

```
   'use strict';

// Start Remove the ability to select //
$(".mealType, .categoryTitle, .categoryContent, .table").attr('unselectable', 'on').css('user-select', 'none').on('selectstart', false);
// End Remove the ability to select //

    $(function(){
        $('.categoryTitle').on('click', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.next('div').slideToggle(200);
        });

        $('.add').on('click', function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                $elementToClone = $this.parent(),
                $myCartDetails = $this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().children().children().next().children();



            if ($myCartDetails.children().hasClass('addCloned')) {
                $($myCartDetails.children()).removeClass('addCLoned').detach();
            } else {
                $elementToClone.clone(true,true).appendTo($myCartDetails).addClass('addCloned');
            }
        });
    });
```

### CSS code if needed

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
}

.mealType {
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px silver;
}

.menu, .myCart {
    margin-top:0rem;
    padding: 10px;
}

.categoryTitle {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, Tahoma, Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.categoryContent {
    display: none;
}

.categoryTitle, .myCartTitle {
    text-align: center;
}

table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}

table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #EEE;
}

table td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, Tahoma, Arial;
}

td img {
    width: 30px;
}

table tr td:nth-of-type(4),table tr td:nth-of-type(5) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

the idea is Add to cart by javascript I tried the clone with the argument (true,true) but still I am not able to apply the idea that I want I tried a lot of things but I am really unable to apply the idea that I want so I posted in stackoverflow hopefully there's a hero will guide me to the right way to apply like this idea and I really appreciate his effort I am waiting for you guys thanks a lot.

[Click To See Simple Image Of The Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X6s1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $myCartDetails = $this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().children().children().next().children();
```

You really need to go back and learn the fundamental concepts of javascript, html, and css before you even try to make a cart.

Comment: I know there's easier way to access the element but I was trying to type what in my mind and focus on the main idea not on how to select the element I have already studied courses about html, css and javascript so please if you have valuable answer do it with all respect if you don't please go make a project with your mastered html, css and javascript instead of wasting your time and my time also you mentioned html and css would you like to tell me what is the problem of them in my code it's just sample not a full site. Thanks

Comment: No, it's not about mastery. It's about basic concepts. The code doesn't make any sense at all - and that's why it doesn't work. You need to start with simpler concepts.

Comment: guide me then instead of disappointing me man, the selector is working fine but I don't understand why it cause the problem kindly explain to me if you have time and help me I really need help I am confused I have already took a lot of basics courses I am just a new person graduated at 2017 now I am starting my career trip trying to apply some ideas I am not the good programmer I am in the level of beginners but now there's a goal I wanna achieve which is to be able to apply this idea and what required to apply it I am ready to learn it.

Comment: by the way I am sorry if my language was tough I was disappointed little bit and I feel that all of the time that I spent to learn was nothing an it was a waste of time I love coding but still not be able to learn it in the right and correct way just think about it when you love something so much and you feel you can do beautiful things but you are not able to find the right materials and courses to learn it in the right way it's really made me so sad and disappointed specially in our Arabic Community the companies only accept person with experience so no chance for us as a new people :(

Comment: Trust me dude it takes time to learn how to code. The basic concepts come hard but once you get them you pick it up quicker. The problem probably *isn't* in the selector but the way it is written is bad. You could assign an id to one of those divs or tables, and then select that. Take a look at this I wrote: https://pyronexus.com/stats/script.js

You can see it working here: https://pyronexus.com/stats/index.html#minimal

Comment: Thank you for your advice and thank you for your time I understand your point I will try to keep trying to learn in correct way can you advice me to free courses and good courses ? about adding id you mean that  I need to give each one an id which will be easier to be selected I got this point but do you have any idea about refreshing the cloned element after make change on the original one I need only this point and I will consider it as a new thing that I learn

Comment: You can loop through the child items and increment their id. Just give the table an id, select that, then select the rows, loop through that with `for (let row in rows) { let object = rows[row]; object.id = 'myRow' + row; }` or similar... this is just off the top of my head but my code there I linked you to does it. It takes a json 'name' and creates a row with that id.

Comment: By the way, I've been coding for over 18 years (I'm 30 now) :)

Comment: By the way, since 2017 is quite a short time to be graduated from something you learnt in university... I think you're trying to leap before you can walk and are trying to solve complex problems before you know how to tackle them effectively... But you'll get there, just take your time. Welcome to programming https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/the-birth-and-death-of-javascript

Comment: Thank you for your effort and I will try to go step by step